# How to set MIME encoding in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to call the following `show` function which has the signature: `function show(io::IO, ::MIME"text/plain", holder::Int)`. What do I need to do with the 2nd argument such that I can call this function? I am unsure what `"::MIME"text/plain"` is asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of

```
julia> show(stdout, "text/plain", "hi")
"hi"
julia> show(stdout, MIME("text/plain"), "hi")
"hi"
julia> show(stdout, MIME"text/plain"(), "hi")
"hi"
```

work. The first one is because there's an overload that passes the second argument to the `MIME` constructor. The two latter ones are just different ways of constructing the mime type:

```
julia> MIME("text/plain") == MIME"text/plain"()
true

julia> MIME"text/plain"()
MIME type text/plain
```